# Agrupar com Lambda, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

to com uma questão aqui. tenho uma *action* que recebe dois parametros, duas datas. isso faz gerar uma lista, só que nessa lista, o mesmo item ta se repetindo. queria tbm, poder fazer uma soma de gasto.
Para que se possa compreender melhor, o sistema é de gerenciamento de uma garagem. Então eu tenho a Vr(requisição de veículo - classe), Mv(Movimentação de Veículo - Classe), e Veículo - Classe.

Classe Mv

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public decimal CombustivelAbastecido { get; set; }
```

A classe Vr(Requisição de veículo), tem o veículo.
o relatório que eu quero mostrar, recebe as duas datas, inicial, e final, então mostraria os veículos solicitados nesse período, um veículo foi solicitado mais de uma vez nesse periodo, e teve um Gasto "X", então queria que ficasse mais ou menos assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho a classe Combustivel, que tem o valor e a descrição.
O Gasto de Combustivel, seria a soma de todo CombustivelAbastecido, que tem na classe Mv(Movimentação De Veículo)

O Jeito que eu to Fazendo:

public ActionResult RelatorioDatadois(DateTime? dataInicio, DateTime? dataFim)
        {

```
        ViewBag.dataInicial = dataInicio;
        ViewBag.dataFinal = dataFim;

        if (dataInicio == null && dataFim == null)
        {
            var vrDb = db.VrDb.Where(v => v.DataSolicitacao >= dataInicio && v.DataSolicitacao <= dataFim).OrderBy(v => v.DataSolicitacao).ToList();
            return View(vrDb);
        }

        else
        {
            var vrDb = db.VrDb.Where(v => v.DataSolicitacao >= dataInicio && v.DataSolicitacao <= dataFim && v.Situacao == Situacao.Finalizado).OrderBy(v => v.DataSolicitacao).ToList();


            var data = dataInicio;
            var dataF = dataFim;

            var tot = db.VrDb.Sum(v => v.Mv.Consumo); //Mostra o Total gasto

            if (tot == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Total = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Total = tot;
            }

            var abastecido = db.VrDb.Sum(v => v.Mv.CombustivelAbastecido);
            if (abastecido == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Abastecido = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Abastecido = abastecido;
            }



            var TotalValorEmDinheiro = db.VrDb.Sum(v => v.Veiculo.Combustivel.Preco * v.Mv.CombustivelAbastecido);

            if (TotalValorEmDinheiro == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.TotalValorEmDinheiro = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.TotalValorEmDinheiro = TotalValorEmDinheiro;
            }


            return View(vrDb);
            //return RedirectToAction("RelatorioTotalPorData", vrDb);

        }

    }
```

Desse jeito ta me trazendo dessa forma
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, ta repetindo o mesmo veículo.Sem contar que o gasto, ta me trazendo a mesma coisa.

Comment: Tem como você postar suas estruturas de classes para analisarmos?

Comment: Se você quer que seja agrupado por veículo faça : 

`db.VrDb.Where(v => v.DataSolicitacao >= dataInicio && v.DataSolicitacao <= dataFim && v.Situacao == Situacao.Finalizado).OrderBy(v => v.DataSolicitacao).GroupBy(v => v.Descricao).ToList();`

Ou ao invés da descrição  o identificador do veículo.

Comment: Desse Jeito sempre da esse erro:
O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,GaragemModel.Vr]]', mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GaragemModel.Vr]'.

 var vrDb =  db.VrDb.Where(v => v.DataSolicitacao >= dataInicio && v.DataSolicitacao <= dataFim && v.Situacao == Situacao.Finalizado).OrderBy(v => v.DataSolicitacao).GroupBy(v => v.Veiculo.Descricao).ToList(); e onde é a tag groupBy, não é só v.Descrição, V é Vr, então é v.Veiculo.Descricao